# What are the landau parameters for thin film and ceramic of Lead zirconate titanate PZT at any particular concentration?

Tags: solid-state-physics

I have got the values for some PZT ( 60/40, 70/30, 80/20, 90/10, 50/50 - ceramic) but have not got for any PZT thin film other than PZT52/48. the coefficients for thin film and ceramic of PZT at particular concentration would be useful ...

Comment: Basically, you are asking if anybody has a good model across concentration ranges? Or what?

Comment: i am looking for parameters so that i can study the phenomenological behavior of thin film and ceramic of PZT using Landau and Landau Devon-shire theory. i have got parameters for PZT52/48, thin film but not its corresponding ceramic values ... so i am asking for piezoelectric coefficients of PZT thin film and ceramic at particular concentration....

Comment: Well, first, do you have reason to believe the parameters are widely different between bulk (what I assume you mean by ‘ceramic’) and thin film?

Comment: Basically, in case of bulk based on the values i have got, yes they are different in their own manner like to order of 10 or 10^2, and based on concentration their transition temp. (para-ferro and vice) too vary... alike there might be some range of variation over thin films form aswell .. may be / i dont know...